# READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is always denied on Android 13 device

Tags: android-13, activityresultcontracts

My application targets api level 32. When running on Android 13 device, ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions() always returns PERMISSION_DENIED even if the user presses on "Allow".

Also, when checking in settings->app->permissions, the IMAGE, AUDIO and VIDEO permissions get granted.

The documentation clearly states that applications targeting api level < 33 should continue asking for READ_EXTERNAL_DEVICE, and the IMAGE, AUDIO and VIDEO will be granted automatically

Tried allowing READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Expected to open Gallery.

Actually, permission was denied.

Comment: Read my answer for a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74898756/6321878

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, From android 13 and beyond You need to put permissions for READ_MEDIA_VIDEO,READ_MEDIA_IMAGES,READ_MEDIA_AUDIO, not Just requesting READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE will work alone, won't even show in the permission page in the settings

```html
<!-- Required only if your app needs to access images or photos
     that other apps created. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />

<!-- Required only if your app needs to access videos
     that other apps created. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />

<!-- Required only if your app needs to access audio files
     that other apps created. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />

<!-- If your app doesn't need to access media files that other apps created,
     set the "maxSdkVersion" attribute to "28" instead. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                 android:maxSdkVersion="32" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                 android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
```

Comment: Why WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORATE is set to max 29?